# How to convert bitmap to file in kotlin using fragment?

Tags: file, kotlin, bitmap, multipart

I want to get my image profile data. I have the bitmap, but the required type for image is MultipartBody How can I change bitmap to this type?

Here's my code to load the image. I use fragment:

```
private val cameraResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                val bitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                binding.ivProfile.loadImage(bitmap)
            }
        }
```

and Here's the warning I got:
[Type mismatch: inferred type is ActivityResultLauncher<Intent!> but MultipartBody.Part was expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Zp5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but if your trying to save an image in the Imageviw that you get from the gallery then you can do something as follow:

```
  private val cameraResult = registerForActivityResult( ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        val data = result.data
        if (data != null){
            val selectedImageUri = data.data
            if (selectedImageUri != null){
                try {
                    val inputStream = requireActivity().contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImageUri)
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                    binding.ivProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }catch (e : Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but i got the same warning, that the type of imageResult variable still  "ActivityResultLauncher<Intent!>". and the required type for this, is MultipartBody.Part. I don't know much about this, but i know that we need "register for activity result" to replace "onActivityResult" that usually use in activity. And i don't know why kotlin read this as a variable type. Btw, thank you for answering, hope you know the answer for this question too..

Comment: are you trying to upload an image to the server using retrofit?

Comment: yes. Can I ask you something? In my server, the required type for image is String($binary). What that means? Is it an url or others? Thank you

Comment: it would be better if you could add your code over here.

Comment: I ask my friend that in the same project with me, and the type for image is String or Url. But I still can't get it. My friends send me some example code, but it write in activity and i write in fragment. So when i write several code, it doesn't exist in Fragment. Lemme show you the code in Activity. Sorry for troubleing you like this, I'm trully new at android kotlin.

Comment: we are here to help and this is what for.

Comment: This is the code in that example project. We use ViewModel. The full is in here for Activity <https://codeshare.io/N30p14>. and for ViewModel: <https://codeshare.io/vwgjyy>. Thank you very much for helping. I confuse about code in the launcherGallery variabel, when we're in activity, we can directly convert uri to file, but when i try it in fragment, it doesn't work. My friend says that we just need get url from image, but the image is from local image. Is it possible we can get url from local image?

Comment: Is that your all code? and Yes, we can get URL from local storage

Comment: Is it okay if we move to chat? just in case if this feels difficult.

Comment: okay, sure we can .

Comment: that is the example code that my friend send me. In my code, I can display images from the gallery but can't save them to the server. This is my code, for Fragment: <https://codeshare.io/3AMWY6> and this is my viewModel: <https://codeshare.io/Lw0xnl> Thank you..

Comment: Sorry, but it seems i can't start a conversation. it is beacuse I haven't reached 100 reputation yet or other reason. I don't know how..

Comment: Or do you have any chat application? its up to you because you're the one who help me.